# gdb to print contents of: const set<Int4> & var_name

Tags: c++, gdb

A package of C++ code I am trying to modify (not mine, and this thing is both large and inscrutable) calls several C++ methods with this parameter:

```
const set<Int4> & var_name
```

The program was called with a command line parameter that should have set values of 2147483647 and 2.  The size() method
seems to indicate that these are in there, but no luck so far getting them out again within gdb:

```
(gdb) p tax_ids.size()
$13 = 2
(gdb) p tax_ids
$14 = std::set with 2 elementsTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/../share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 405, in next
    item = item.cast(self.type).dereference()['_M_value_field']
RuntimeError: There is no member or method named _M_value_field.
(gdb)  p *tax_ids
No symbol "operator*" in current context.
```

The place where the values are finally extracted is unfortunately implemented as a pile of nested defines, so it is difficult to see exactly what is going on.  Pretty sure though that all it is doing is using var_name.begin() or some similar method to create an iterator and then repeatedly dereferencing the iterator to extract the integer values for each iterator increment.  Is there some way to do that in gdb?

Answer (score 2):

> `Traceback (most recent call last): ...`

This error indicates that the GDB STL pretty-printers installed in `/usr/share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/...` on your system do *not* match the version of `libstdc++` you are actually using.

There could be several reasons:

- you didn't update `libstdc++-dbg` (or whatever package `/usr/share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py` actually belongs to) when you updated `libstdc++`.
- you aren't using `libstdc++` at all (perhaps you are using `libc++` and building with Clang)

The appropriate fix will depend on the root cause, and your question doesn't contain enough info. You'll have to dig a bit yourself.

For reference, when the STL pretty printers and libstdc++ do match, here is what the output looks like:

```
$ cat t.cc
#include <set>

size_t fn(const std::set<int>& foo)
{
  return foo.size();
}

int main()
{
  const std::set<int> foo = { 3, 7 };
  return fn(foo);
}

$ g++ -g t.cc && gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) b fn
Breakpoint 1 at 0xa86: file t.cc, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, fn (foo=std::set with 2 elements = {...}) at t.cc:5
5     return foo.size();
(gdb) p foo
$1 = std::set with 2 elements = {[0] = 3, [1] = 7}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! The build was on Centos 6 using Devtoolset 7. Most likely the gdb was the default one for that OS and not the Devtoolset one. Thanks.

Comment: Found it - the gdb rpm for devtoolset-7 was not installed.  When gdb was invoked, even with devtoolset-7 enabled, it used the system's default gdb.  After installing that RPM when devtoolset-7 was enabled it used the right gdb and that could print the set without errors.